# How to create a XSD file with strict value validation based on a XML File in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have an undefined number of XML files all with a different structure, these files are needed as "golden files" to validate another batch of XML files.

I have thought of a couple of different approaches to this, but lastly I decided that XSD files propably is the way to go.

This is my current solution:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(Path);
XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
XmlSchemaInference schema = new XmlSchemaInference();
schema.Occurrence = XmlSchemaInference.InferenceOption.Restricted;
schema.TypeInference = XmlSchemaInference.InferenceOption.Restricted;
schemaSet = schema.InferSchema(reader);

XmlWriter writer;
foreach (XmlSchema s in schemaSet.Schemas())
{
     writer = XmlWriter.Create(Path.ChangeExtension(Path, ".xsd"));
     s.Write(writer);
     writer.Close();
}
reader.Close();
```

This works, however it only creates a XSD file which validates the structure of a XML file, I would like a XSD file which also validates the values in the XML files, is there a way to automatically create a XSD file based on a XML file.

*If you have a better solution to my problem, I would be happy to hear it.*

Comment: With "also validates values" you mean something like "int value can be between 1 and 5 inclusive"?

Comment: And you need to create the XSDs dynamically based on example XML files and automatically (without anyone needing to manually adjust anything)? Did I get that right?

Comment: @Fildor Yes, I saw an example on a another thread which validated string values to be a specific value, which is what I am looking for. It would be very much preffered if these XSD files could be created without any manual adjusting.

Comment: If your XML file doesn't contain any information about the allowed ranges, then clearly it isn't possible for *anything* to infer the allowed ranges.

Comment: No.  The XSD generators do not know the types so even if you automatically generated the XSD you will need to modify the types.  You also may need to add qualifiers if values are required or not required.

Comment: I might be missing something, but all of the XML files have actual values inside, I was hoping it is possible to use these values as ranges.

Comment: That very much depends on what the values represent; for example an `int AgeInDays` field would be difficult to generate validation for since one XML file might have that set to 10 and another one 40. Does that mean that only 10 or 40 should be allowed? Or only numbers between 10 and 40? But the likelyhood that is the correct range is probably zero.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I see your point, except what I was thinking is to have one xsd file per xml file, a 1:1 ratio. I am not looking at a specific range, for my values, more like a check if the value is the same. I dont even need the type validation, just the value validation. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "golden files"? Presumably the files being validated are expected to match the golden files: that is, they will be in some ways the same as the golden files but in other ways different. Then the problem reduces to defining what must be the same and what is expected to be different.

Comment: @MichaelKay The point with the "golden files", is to set a standard for what the right structure and values are, the expected outcome is to make sure nothing is different, but if it is different, It should tell me what and where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test that a given file is "the same as" some reference file, I don't think schema validation is the right tool for the job - although it's an intriguing option, especially with XSD 1.1 assertions.

The two most common approaches are

(a) turn both files into canonical XML format and compare them as strings

(b) use the `fn:deep-equal()` function to compare them as trees, using XPath 2.0+.

Unfortunately neither approach is very good at telling you where the differences are. Saxon has an extension saxon:deep-equal() that tries to report the difference, but to be honest (as its author) the output is not always easy to follow.

For testing, my preferred approach is to express expected test results in terms of a set of XPath assertions that must be satisfied. This makes it easy to exclude stuff that's allowed to vary (such as thing that depend on date and time), and by knowing which assertion failed, you can identify the cause of the problem more easily.

Consider XSpec for testing.

Comment: This XSpec thing have definently gotten my attention, altough I cannot use it in this project. Another solution I had worked up is to compare the two different files line by line, but since the structure can deviate a bit because of the way the XML files are created, this was not a viable solution. Your XPath idea might be worth looking further into, as I have already thought about this solutions, without coming up with a good solution. Thank you for the answer.